# How do I get to get buttons in a webpage to control a program

Tags: javascript, php, button, command, html

How do I get buttons in a HTML webpage to control a series of commad-line programs, by executing the program when the button is held down, and stopping when the button is released - if desperate the mouse button being pressed could just start the command, and the button being released could send to kill it - but a quick response time would be nice.

The commands I want to execute are either some bash scripts or some python scripts - which it does execute not matter to much.

I have mapped the buttons to an image, and used the Javascript events `onmousedown=` and `onmouseup=` to control the commands - but how do I get these to execute the commands, with a script creating a web page? At a guess I will need the javascript to run some PHP functions, but I am an utter noob when it comes to php...

This will need to work on a Fedora/Ubuntu linux machine, preferably in Firefox, and **later** be adapted for an Android tablet, *perhaps in a QT app if I can by head around qt-creator*

Comment: Are you thinking that you will be able to run these scripts on the client's computer? If so, you cannot.

Comment: These are all my computers and devices that I am planning to use

Comment: What do you mean by appliances? My question is - where are these scripts running?

Comment: These scripts run through a ssh tunnel - that all works, that control a raspberry pi, and just tell it to do basic commands, no login required etc. *Hopefully the horse can push as well as pull, @mjayt, and I would prefer to use a tax-paying search engine :-)*. Also, I don't want to generate PHP pages, just small functions would do. I have done a few little ones before, so should be able to get my head around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome offers native messaging, which may do what you want. you will need a helper program. Right now I'm reading http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#native-messaging

Comment: Could there be a method that would integrated into the webpage, and not need modifications to the actual browser in use? *I would prefer to use Firefox, as that works better with other functions the page has to perform, like viewing webcam output in a iframe.* Nice idea though.

Comment: You need to breach the security model, so something like mozplugger or  a helper web server is needed. I recommended as I did because you mentioned android, but in hindsight I think I should have mentioned Native Client and Pepper, but that has a lot different model.

Comment: I just saw your mention of ssh and rpi, what you want to do is run a web server on your rpi, and have cgi wrappers around your commands. much less hassle.

Comment: I already have all the data required transmitted to and from the pi, from  control commands to the video output. The pi produces a hidden locked hotspot which my laptop detects and logs into. For ssh, then I have an RSA key on my Pi and my laptop, meaning that the computer can access all of the Pi without passwords, but not the other-way round. I thought of a generated webserver, but the Pi is already outputting the webcam output on one, so one on my laptop would be better due to full bandwidth usage, so my laptop just needs a web server that can run commands - all the rest is fine.